npx webpack is not working OR npx "anything-inside-node_modules" not working
When I run npx webpack it doesn't work and when I searched the whole internet Nothing solved my issue, everyone suggested installing it globally with npm install -g webpack webpack-cli --save-dev.
but this message will always appear after I run npx webpack :
'CSJS\Project\to-do-list\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Mus\Documents\AnyThingForCODING\webpack\bin\webpack.js' at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [] }

I am raising this question because I found the solution to my specific problem and maybe others are facing the same issue that I have and don't know why all other solutions aren't working.
My path project was this "C:\Users\Mus\Documents\AnyThingForCODING\HTML&CSJS\Project\to-do-list"
the only problem was because I had a special character -> '&'.
I replaced it with this path :
"C:\Users\Mus\Documents\AnyThingForCODING\HTML-CSJS\Project\to-do-list"

I replaced '&' with a '-'.
This problem that I was facing might occur if your path has any special characters that are not a normal hyphen '-' or an underscore '_'.
Spaces will also cause this problem, so a path like this :
"C:\Users\Mus\Documents\AnyThingForCODING\HTML CSJS\Project\to do list"
will lead to the same error.

And please do share your approaches if u solved it in another way, I actually can't tell technically why this problem occurs but maybe it has something to do with how npm checks the paths and may not recognize special characters like & or spaces.
